# AsyncSocket setDelegate not working?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, asyncsocket

I am working on a server for a game using AsyncSocket class. I am trying to relocate the reading/writing from the server object to a player object after the connection has been made and the handling the socket object to the player:

Here is the connection method from the server

```
- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didAcceptNewSocket:(AsyncSocket *)newSocket {
    [self logMessage:@"Incoming Client" withColor:[NSColor greenColor]];

    Player *p=[[Player alloc] initWithConnection:newSocket];
    [_players addObject:p];
    [p release];

    [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] dockTile] setBadgeLabel:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",[_players count]]];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

in my Player.m class i have the following `initWithconnection:` method (excerpt):

```
- (id)initWithConnection:(AsyncSocket *)connection {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    ...
    _connection=[connection retain];
    if ([_connection canSafelySetDelegate]) {
      [_connection setDelegate:self];
    }
  }
  return self;
}
```

I am implementing the needed delegate methods (in fact, i just copied & pasted them from the former server object to test it), but it seems to me that the `setDelegate:` method simply doesnt work as expected. It wont get called. Leaving the delegate being set to the server object everything is ok (i just have to pass the incoming message to the correct player object).

Anyone have an idea what i am doing wrong here?

thanks
/D

Comment: I found it: i forgot to copy one of the delegate methods (`-(void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(uint16_t)p` where the subsequent read from the socket had to be initiated.